# Sublime Text 2 RegEx replace n with n+1

Tags: regex, replace, sublimetext2

Using RegEx search and replace with Sublime Text 2, how can I replace my pattern matches (n) with n+1? And if there is no way to do this with search and replace, is there another easy way to do it?

My RegEx pattern is `^(\d{1,4})\n`, and I'd like to be able to do `$1+1`, which currently just outputs the match with a literal "+1".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regex is the wrong tool for that function. However, there is Sublime Text plugin just to do what you want: ["Sublime Text plugin to increment/decrement all selected numbers"](https://gist.github.com/2788978)

Comment: My god! Of course there's a plugin! It's simple to create functionality yourself, but if you're feeling lazy or don't know how, there's a plugin. This is starting to feel a bit like Drupal. Only much more awesome. Thanks for the answer!