# regex algorithm converter

Tags: regex, validation

I need to validate a VAT number (9 digits long) which has the following validation scheme.

Let's assume that 9 digits as `d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 d6 d7 d8 d9` where :

`(d1*256 + d2*128 + d3*64 + d4*32 + d5*16 + d6*8 + d7*4 + d8*2) / 11 = d9`

all the above sum divided by 11 equals `d9`.

Is it possible to validate this VAT number with a Regular Expression and if yes how?

Comment: which programming language are you using ? IMHO, you'd be better of validating this with JavaScript on the front-end and your back-end language. You're computing values, not pattern matching.

Comment: Just curious -- which country uses that scheme? *Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know,
I'll use regular expressions.”  Now they have two problems.* -- *Jamie Zawinski*

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to do this with regex. I've seen some wild things that you can do with Regex (e.g. [Is it possible to increment numbers using regex substitution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12941362/is-it-possible-to-increment-numbers-using-regex-substitution/12942634)).

However this is probably always a bad idea. It is much easier (and much more readable) to just convert the numbers to integers and do the check with your favorite programming language instead.