# Regular expression to replace number in increment order in TextPad

Tags: regex, notepad++, textpad

I want to replace increment number using regular expression in TextPad. I have below code and I want increment number between tag `<EndToEndId>` and `</EndToEndId>` and number should remain 8 digits.

```
        <PmtId>
           <EndToEndId>80000001</EndToEndId>
        </PmtId>
        <PmtTpInf>
              <Prtry>PM</Prtry>
        </PmtTpInf>
       <PmtId>
       <PmtId>
           <EndToEndId>80000002</EndToEndId>
        </PmtId>
        <PmtTpInf>
              <Prtry>PM</Prtry>
        </PmtTpInf>
       <PmtId>
       ......
       <PmtId>
           <EndToEndId>800000010</EndToEndId>
        </PmtId>
        <PmtTpInf>
              <Prtry>PM</Prtry>
        </PmtTpInf>
       <PmtId>
```

I have tried myself to come up with solution but after 80000009, it gives 800000010 which is 9 digit number.

I have provided below regular expression in *Find And Replace* option in TextPad.

Find What: `(<EndToEndId>).*?(</EndToEndId>)`
Replace With: `(<EndToEndId>)\i(</EndToEndId>)`

I have searched similar solution on Stackoverflow using Notepadd++ from [Notepad++ incrementally replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602816/notepad-incrementally-replace)
 but it doens't give increment number when there are other tags like `<PmtId>, <PmtTpInf>`

Could you please help me to solve this issue as I have tried myself a lot and now asking on Stackoverflow. Thank you.

Comment: It's possible, in two steps following this [answer about incrementing numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31599758/1507014)

Comment: You can't do that, in your case, with a text editor. You have to write a script in your favorite scripting language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do two passes.

The first pass as you are currently doing, producing results like:

```
80000001
80000009
800000010
800000099
8000000100
8000000999
```

then a second pass to correct the lengths:

```
Search:  80+(\d{6})\b
Replace: 8$1
```

Which produces the following result from the above sample intermediate output:

```
8000001
8000009
8000010
8000099
8000100
8000999
```