# Smart (iterative and incremental) copy and paste using regex

Tags: regex

I want to define (#define) 10 IR with its respective pin numbers

```
#define IR1 A1
#define IR2 A2
....
#define IR10 A10
```

the difference is in only digits, it just incrementing by 1

how to use regex to copy

```
#define IR1 A1
```

and paste as

```
#define IR2 A2
```

and so on...

and at last, I want to write only one line code and get 9 or more lines of code,

there is no need knowledge of Arduino, just I want to get an incremental copy of

```
#define IR1 A1
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12941362

Comment: This isn't really a coding question, but an editor or IDE question, and consequently there would be one answer per editor. Most of those answers would be ‘this is hard’. Myself, I'd do this with jot + sed outside the editor if I had 10s of lines to generate, but for fewer than 20–30 lines that would probably be more hassle than copying the line multiple times and tweaking it by hand. You don't have to automate _everything_.

Comment: In other words: doable? Sort of. Valuable? No: use a real editor you can script, and make it actually useful.

Comment: @NormanGray IMO regex questions are completely on-topic, and are programming--regex area well-known DSL. Is it a good solution for this problem? No. But on-topic.

Comment: @DaveNewton Sure, regexes are programming (and that's why I didn't edit away that tag). But this is at heart a ‘how do I use my editor?’ question.

Comment: @NormanGray It's a "how do i increment a number via regex" question.

Comment: Its a 1 liner in Perl `$str =~ s/IR(\d+) A(\d+)/IR$1+1 A$2+1/e` basically a replacement callback

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with a loop in a one-liner use-your-favourite-language script.

For example, in Perl:

```
perl -e 'for (my $i=0; $i<10; ++$i) { print "#define IR$i A$i\n"; }'
```

or in bash:

```
for i in `seq 1 10`; do echo "#define IR$i A$i"; done
```

To be honest, I see no need to do this in a regex. Just run the above and cut and paste the results into your editor.